# Lombok Nullable value

Tags: java, lombok, builder

I have the following code using Lombok:

```
class Query1 {

  @Builder
  static class Something{
    Inner inner;

    public Optional<Inner> getInner() {
      return Optional.ofNullable(inner);
    }
  }

  @Value
  static class Inner{
    Integer value;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Integer mayBeNull = 123;
    Something s = Something.builder()
        .inner(mayBeNull == null ? null : new Inner(mayBeNull)) //THIS LINE IS UGLY
        .build();
    System.out.println(s.getInner().map(Inner::getValue).orElse(987));
  }
}
```

Is it possible to somehow shorten this line `mayBeNull == null ? null : new Inner(mayBeNull)` using some Lombok magic, or is there some other idiom that I could use here? Basically if `Inner` value is null, there is no reason for me to set `inner` field inside `Something` at all.

The only thing that comes up to my mind is manually adding:

```
  @Value
  static class Inner{
    Integer value;

    public static Inner ofNullable(Integer value){
      return value!=null ? new Inner(value) : null;
    }
  }
```

and then using it as a `.inner(Inner.ofNullable(mayBeNull))` but this one also doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: is the reason you want to do this to avoid a call to `Inner` constructor if value is null? Apart from that, i dont see any real benefit from it. Also, if `Inner` is just a wrapper for boxed integer, maybe you can unwrap it and put it directly in `Something`.

Answer (score 1):

You can move this `null` check and `Inner` object creation into the builder. We can customize a Lombok builder. We write the parts of the builder that we want to customize and the Lombok `@Builder` annotation will simply not generate those parts, but just extend builder with missed fields.

**Example 1, additional method for `Inner` field initialization:**

```java
@Builder
public class Something {
    Inner inner;
    ClassA classA;

    public Optional<Inner> getInner() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(inner);
    }

    public static class SomethingBuilder {
        private Inner inner;;

        public SomethingBuilder innerInt(Integer mayBeNull) {
            this.inner = mayBeNull == null ? null : new Inner(mayBeNull); // or Inner.ofNullable(mayBeNull)
            return  this;
        }
    }
}
```

Generated code:

```java
    public static class SomethingBuilder {
        private Inner inner;;
        private ClassA classA;

        SomethingBuilder() {
        }

        public SomethingBuilder innerInt(Integer mayBeNull) {
            this.inner = mayBeNull == null ? null : new Inner(mayBeNull);
            return  this;
        }

        public SomethingBuilder inner(Inner inner) {
            this.inner = inner;
            return this;
        }

        public SomethingBuilder classA(ClassA classA) {
            this.classA = classA;
            return this;
        }

        public Something build() {
            return new Something(inner, classA);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Something.SomethingBuilder(inner=" + this.inner + ", classA=" + this.classA + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2, replace method for `Inner` field initialization:**

```java
@Builder
public class Something {
    Inner inner;
    ClassA classA;

    public Optional<Inner> getInner() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(inner);
    }

    public static class SomethingBuilder {
        private Inner inner;;

        public SomethingBuilder inner(Integer mayBeNull) {
            this.inner = mayBeNull == null ? null : new Inner(mayBeNull);// or Inner.ofNullable(mayBeNull)
            return  this;
        }
    }
}
```

Generated code:

```java
    public static class SomethingBuilder {
        private Inner inner;;
        private ClassA classA;

        SomethingBuilder() {
        }

        public SomethingBuilder inner(Integer mayBeNull) {
            this.inner = mayBeNull == null ? null : new Inner(mayBeNull);
            return  this;
        }

        public SomethingBuilder classA(ClassA classA) {
            this.classA = classA;
            return this;
        }

        public Something build() {
            return new Something(inner, classA);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Something.SomethingBuilder(inner=" + this.inner + ", classA=" + this.classA + ")";
        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

```java
        Something something1 = Something.builder().innerInt(null).build();
        Something something2 = Something.builder().innerInt(123).build();
        Something something3 = Something.builder().inner(new Inner(123)).build();
```